# Life cycle of UIVIew controller+iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, nsmutablearray, lifecycle

I want to clear about the life cycle of the UIVIEWCONTROLLER in iphone:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];
    }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{   
return 3;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return 50.0;
}


//This is the method which will be called and IS REQ since we impl interface/delegate
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//We use own own table cell now instead of default
UITableViewCell *cell   =   [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"XMl_CELL"];    
//Our cell has images and text
Wsp = [[WebServiceParser alloc]initWithURLMy:@"http://api.geonames.org/findN"];
return cell;
}

 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 

//MyParserData *data=(MyParserData*)[arrayTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//NSLog(@"Here->%@",data.url);
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:TRUE];
}
```

Please explain to me  which method will call first and why.

I want to call one method for web service parsing then according to its response i want to put the row count and changes in the table view.

i had tried to alloc on array in viewdidload method and set the row count according to the count of the array.But it is giving me bad_access.Becoz it is not allocing the proper count.

Please explain if any one had any idea..
Thanks in advance

Comment: please post ur code with formating from ur xcode.but now it has changed by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope my code would help you as I don't understand your question properly

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    myApp = (myAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(startParsing) withObject:nil];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void) startParsing
{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startIndicator) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];   

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.aaaa.org"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    // 2 -- parsing
    parser = [[myParser alloc] init];

    [parser parseXML:data];
    [data release];
    [parser print];

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateTable) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    [pool release]; 

}

- (void) startIndicator
{
    av.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [av startAnimating];
}

- (void) updateTable
{
    [av stopAnimating];
    [myTable reloadData];

}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    int n = [myApp.myParsedDataArray count];
    return n ; 
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    int cellHeight = 70 ;
    return cellHeight; 
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   // code
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   //Code
}
```

I have used an array, that stores parsed data, in delegate file so that I can use it anywhere.

Hope it gives you an idea...

Answer (score 4):

This is explained well in the [View Controller Programmers Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: New link here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

Why not put an NSLog in each method and run it to see the order?

Also, it looks like you are populating the cells/rows with a network call for each cell (and never releasing the allocs - you probably want to autorelease those) - so why do you need an array?